# Ruby BCrypt hash comparison

Tags: ruby, bcrypt

I'm trying to implement what seems like a very simple authentication approach using Sinatra and BCrypt but clearly I'm missing something...

Users are preassigned a temporary password which is stored in plaintext in the db.

I authenticate against the temp password and then create both a salt and password_hash and write them as strings to the db (mongo in this case).

To authenticate I fetch the salt from the db and user password to compare.

```
post "/password_reset" do
  user = User.first(:email => params[:email], :temp_password => params[:temp_password])
  if dealer != nil then
  password_salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
  password_hash = BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(params[:password], password_salt)
  user.set(:password_hash => password_hash)
  user.set(:password_salt => password_salt)
  end
end

post "/auth" do
  @user = User.first(:email => params[:email])
  @user_hash = BCrypt::Password.new(@user.password_hash) #because the password_hash is  stored in the db as a string, I cast it as a BCrypt::Password for comparison
  if @user_hash == BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(params[:password], @user.password_salt.to_s)   then
    auth = true
  else
    auth = false
  end
end
```

The value returned by BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(params[:password], password_salt) is different than what is stored in the db (both are of class BCrypt::Password, but they don't match).

What am I missing here? Many thanks in advance for any insight!

Marc

Answer (score 24):

`BCrypt::Password` is a subclass of `String`, and it [overrides the `==` method](https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby/blob/v3.0.1/lib/bcrypt.rb#L175-178) to make checking passwords easier. When you do

```
if @user_hash == BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(params[:password], @user.password_salt.to_s)
```

you end up performing the hash *twice*, and so they don’t match. If you compared directly with `@user.password_hash` rather than using `BCrypt::Password.new` you should see that they match.

The more “correct” way to use bcrypt-ruby for passwords is to not use the `Engine` class at all, just the `Password` class. You don’t need to manage the salt yourself, bcrypt takes care of that and includes it in the password hash string:

```
password_salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
password_hash = BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret("s3kr1t!", password_salt)

puts password_salt
puts password_hash
```

produces something like this:

```
$2a$10$4H0VpZjyQO9SoAGdfEB5j.
$2a$10$4H0VpZjyQO9SoAGdfEB5j.oanIOc4zp3jsdTra02SkdmhAVpGK8Z6
```

You’ll get something slightly different if you run it, since a different salt will be generated, but you can see that the password hash includes the salt.

In your case, you want something like this:

```
post "/password_reset" do
  user = User.first(:email => params[:email], :temp_password => params[:temp_password])
  if dealer != nil then
    password_hash = BCrypt::Password.create(params[:password])
    user.set(:password_hash => password_hash) # no need to store the salt separately in the database
  end
end

post "/auth" do
  @user = User.first(:email => params[:email])
  @user_hash = BCrypt::Password.new(@user.password_hash)
  if @user_hash == params[:password]  then # overridden == method performs hashing for us
    auth = true
  else
    auth = false
  end
end
```

Comment: THANK YOU so much. That was exactly what I was missing, works perfectly. I can stop pulling my hair out (until the next thing).

Comment: you could do @user_hash.is_password? params[:password] instead of ==... I think it's more clear and error prone, because if you don't know that == was overwritten and invert the comparison order (params[:password] == @user_hash), it will return false...