# sha1 to brcrypt ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sha1, bcrypt

I have a 4-digit secret code attribute that I encrypt using sha1 at the moment.
As it's not very secure, I'd like to migrate to using bcrypt.

In order to convert the sha1 hash to bcrypt I've written the below rake task

```
namespace :user do
  desc "convert all secret codes encryption from sha1 to bcrypt"

  @rainbow_table = {}

  task secret_code: :environment do
    User.all.each do |user|
      clean_secret_code = @rainbow_table[user.secret_code]
      bcrypted_secret_code = BCrypt::Password.create(clean_secret_code)
      user.update_attributes secret_code: bcrypted_secret_code
      p user.valid_secret_code? clean_secret_code.to_s
    end
  end

  def create_rainbow_table
    ("0000".."9999").each do |i|
      @rainbow_table.merge!(Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(i.to_s) => i.to_s)
    end
  end
end
```

so this works fine, but then when running for my ruby on rails application when I do :

```
BCrypt::Password.new(secret_code) == code.to_s
```

it return `false`
`code` being the secret code that is hashed, and `secret_code` is the encrypted version

Any help would be greatly appreciated

thanks

Comment: You should check the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12028910/ruby-bcrypt-hash-comparison, where you will find your answer.

Comment: thanks @tukan but I don't see anything different from what I'm doing at the moment

Answer (score 0):

ok my bad.

Actually this is working fine, it's just that I was running a callback on the `update_attributes secret_code` which was encrypting the hash again.
I'm now using `updat